Database name has a - (dash) in it - I'm getting an error
if (strpos($db_name, '.') === false) {
    $result = $smcFunc['db_query']('', "SHOW TABLE STATUS FROM {raw:db_name}", array('db_name' => $db_name));
} else {
    $result = $smcFunc['db_query']('', 'SHOW TABLE STATUS FROM ' . $db_name, array());
}

What's wrong with this? I keep getting an error

You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '-353035393de2' at line 1


Are you sure this problem is in any way related to PHP itself? Would running the same query in some tool like phpMyAdmin or MySQL Workbench work better?

no i tryed that but the answer below worked for that file but now it moved on to the next file witch i assume ill have to do the same to all files but im not sure where to put the change

// Create table
if (!checkTableExistsArcade($table['name']))
$smcFunc['db_create_table']('{db_prefix}' . $table_name, $table['columns'], $table['indexes'], array(), 'ignore');
// Update table
else
{
$currentTable = $smcFunc['db_table_structure']('{db_prefix}' . $table_name);

i might add this is not my code i get these errors when trying to install a mod on smf thru package manager

While - is valid as part of an identifier name, you cannot reference an identifier with the - without encapsulating it in quotes:
if (strpos($db_name, '.') === false) {
    $result = $smcFunc['db_query']('', "SHOW TABLE STATUS FROM `{raw:db_name}`", array('db_name' => $db_name));
} else {
    $result = $smcFunc['db_query']('', 'SHOW TABLE STATUS FROM `' . $db_name . '`', array());
}

There may be a more elegant or generally-accepted way to interpolate these quote characters, but it's difficult to say for certain since you haven't provided any information or source code to indicate what's behind the function $smcFunc['db_query']().

USE db_name; SHO TABLE STAUS LIKE 'foo--353035393de2';
